# Replace if condition under forEach statement

Tags: java, java-8

I want to replace if condition with ternary operator.

```
Map<String, Object> resultMap = new HashMap<>();    
reasons.stream().forEach(reason -> {                    
    if(reason.isNotChargable()) {
        resultMap.put("reason1", reason);
    } else {
        resultMap.put("reason2", reason);
    }
});
```

Where **reasons** is a list object.

Comment: Replace this with a loop. No reason at all to use `forEach`.

Comment: why do you want to iterate a collection `reasons` to just put two entries into a `Map`? what is your actual use case? and `isNotChargable()` is not a method of `Object` class!

Comment: Your resultMap will probably contain two keys (reason1 and reason2) along with the last values corresponding to these that were put.

Comment: I was wondering the same as Naman. You are traversing all elements of `reason`, but for each element, you're overwriting the value of either the "reason1" or "reason2" key...

Answer (score 1):

A better alternative to ternary inside the for-each would be to simply create a Map from the Stream but also use ternary to determine key. I assume the object is `Reason` as it's not been included in question.

Props to @Naman for allowing this to handle conflicts when collecting multiple keys that are equal. This will assume the existing value instead of throwing an IllegalStateException.

```java
Map<String, Reason> results = reasons.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(r -> r.isNotChargable() ? "reason1" : "reason2", Function.identity(), (existing, next) -> existing);
```

Comment: merge function? `Collectors.toMap(r -> r.isNotChargable() ? "reason1" : "reason2", Function.identity(), (a,b)->a)` to be precise

Comment: I'm actually unfamiliar, I would definitely appreciate an example and after I research I can update it the original if it's better (which it definitely could be).

Comment: Ah so the point it seems from quick research is to avoid duplicate entries of the same key, and in that case, assume the existing value.

Comment: @Naman thank you, I really appreicate that insight. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this with a loop. No reason at all to use `forEach`.

```
for (ReasonType reason : reasons) {
  resultMap.put(reason.isNotChargeable() ? "reason1" : "reason2", reason);
}
```

(However, you can put this `resultMap.put` into a `forEach`; it's just unnecessary).

Comment: Isn't your loop a for each as well?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
String key = reason.isNotChargable() ? "reason1" : "reason2";
resultMap.put(key , reason);
```